# PHP and SQL update table by specified row

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a table pulling info from a database with the last column of each row being an input tag labeled COMPLETE a user can click on.  I want to be able to click on the tag and have it update my database to change a boolean field which would change COMPLETE from 0 to 1.  Right now, I can't seem to update the rows if I click on them out of order.  so If i click to update the first row and then click a few rows below, it will update the second row.  It will update any row you want if you click the button for that row twice, but first it updates the row where you left off previously...

```
<form action='' method='POST'>
<?php

    $current_date = date("Y-m-d");
    $n = 1;
    $sql = "SELECT id, date, pname, details, time, tech FROM task WHERE task='LAB' AND complete=0 ORDER BY date DESC";
    $result = $link->query($sql);

    echo $current_date;

    echo "<table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Project</th>
                    <th>Details</th>
                    <th>Start Time</th>
                    <th>Technician</th>
                </tr>";

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr align='center'><td>" .$row["date"]. "</td><td>" .$row["pname"]. "</td><td>" 
        .$row["details"]. "</td><td>" .$row["time"]. "</td><td>" .$row["tech"]. "</td>
        <td><input type='submit' name=".$n." value='Complete' /></td></tr>";

        if (isset($_POST[$n])) {
            $id = $row["id"];
            $update = "UPDATE task SET complete = 1 WHERE task='LAB' AND id = ".$id."";
            echo $update;
            $update_result = $link->query($update);
        }
        $n++;
    }
    echo "</table>";

    $link->close();
?>

</form>
```

Comment: So why aren't you using the `id` of each row exactly? And what about security against sql injection?

Comment: You should really work on splitting your display logic from your business logic. I can pretty much guarantee it would resolve this for you.

Comment: What happens if you remove `echo $update;`?

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: I don't really understand the point of the SELECT

Comment: the SELECT statement is executed to retrieve data from the database

Answer (score 2):

One of the things I noticed was you don't do proper [concatenation](http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.concat.php).

---

### ANSWER:

You can try putting `form` for each row, then use hidden input field for storing the `id`:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo '<tr align="center">
              <td>'.$row["date"].'</td>
              <td>'.$row["pname"].'</td>
              <td>'.$row["details"].'</td>
              <td>'.$row["time"].'</td>
              <td>'.$row["tech"].'</td>
              <td>
                  <form action="" method="POST">
                      <input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$row["id"].'">
                      <input type="submit" name="complete" value="Complete"/>
                  </form>
              </td>
          </tr>';
}
```

You can then process the form:

```
if(isset($_POST["complete"])) {
    $id = $_POST["id"];
    $stmt = $link->prepare("UPDATE task SET complete = 1 WHERE task='LAB' AND id = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
}
```

---

### Second Option:

You can try using [Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for seamless transaction:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo '<tr align="center">
              <td>'.$row["date"].'</td>
              <td>'.$row["pname"].'</td>
              <td>'.$row["details"].'</td>
              <td>'.$row["time"].'</td>
              <td>'.$row["tech"].'</td>
              <td>
                  <a href="#" class="btn" type="button" data-artid="'.$row["id"].'">Complete</a>
              </td>
          </tr>';
}
```

Then create your script (I'll be using [jQuery](https://jquery.com/download/) for this example). You may include this at the bottom of your main file:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){ /* PREPARE THE SCRIPT */
        $(".btn").click(function(){ /* WHEN COMPLETE BUTTON IS CLICKED */

            var elem = $(this),
                id = elem.attr('data-artid'); /* GET THE ID OF THE CLICKED ELEMENT */

            $.ajax({ /* PROCESS AJAX */
                url: "process.php", /* THE FILE WHERE THE FORM WILL BE PROCESSED */
                type: "POST", /* METHOD TO BE USED */
                data: {"id":id}, /* THE DATA TO BE PASSED TO process.php */
                dataType: 'json', /* TYPE OF DATA TO BE RETURNED */
                success: function(result){ /* IF process.php IS SUCCESSFUL */
                    if(result.boolean){
                        elem.closest('tr').remove(); /* REMOVE THE ENTIRE ROW */
                    }
                }
            });
            return false; /* THIS WILL PREVENT FROM SCROLLING TO THE TOP OF THE PAGE */
        });
    });
</script>
```

Then process the form in `process.php` (separate file):

```
/** INCLUDE HERE SOMEWHERE YOUR DATABASE CONNECTION **/
$boolean = false; /** DEFAULT VALUE TO BE RETURNED **/

if(!empty($_POST["id"])){
    $id = $_POST["id"];
    $stmt = $link->prepare("UPDATE task SET complete = 1 WHERE task='LAB' AND id = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
    $boolean = true;
} 

echo json_encode(array('boolean' => $boolean)); /* THIS WILL BE RETURNED TO THE AJAX REQUEST */
```

Comment: thank you! tried the first option and it worked. Excellent!